# Change Materials Element 0 of Mesh Renderer to a selected image as a shader

Tags: c#, image, shader, mesh, renderer

As Unity does not provide triangle object, I need to create it by C#.

After adding Mesh Filter and Mesh Renderer by C#, the object cannot add such components again in scene.

I can only change the color of object created.

Now, I need to change Materials Element 0 of Mesh Renderer to a selected image as a shader.

I have tried Resources.Load () and Shader.Find () but they don't work.

How can I do it in C#?  Please explain with code.

Here is my code triangle.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class triangle : MonoBehaviour {
    public Vector3 center;
    public float x1, y1, x2, y2, radius;
    public string color;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        gameObject.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
        gameObject.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        Mesh mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
        Material mat = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
        SphereCollider sc = gameObject.AddComponent(typeof(SphereCollider)) as SphereCollider;
        sc.center = center;
        sc.radius = radius;
        mesh.Clear();

        // make changes to the Mesh by creating arrays which contain the new values
        mesh.vertices = new Vector3[] {new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(x1, y1, 0), new Vector3(x2, y2, 0)};
        mesh.uv = new Vector2[] {new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(0, 1), new Vector2(1, 1)};
        mesh.triangles =  new int[] {0, 1, 2};
        switch (color) {
            case "black": mat.color = new Color (0, 0, 0, 1);  break;
            case "blue": mat.color = new Color (0, 0, 255, 1);  break;
            case "clear": mat.color = new Color (0, 0, 0, 0);  break;
            case "cyan": mat.color = new Color (0, 255, 255, 1);  break;
            case "green": mat.color = new Color (0, 255, 0, 1);  break;
            case "magenta": mat.color = new Color (255, 0, 255, 1);  break;
            case "purple": mat.color = new Color (1, 0, 1, 1);  break;
            case "red": mat.color = new Color (255, 0, 0, 1);  break;
            case "white": mat.color = new Color (255, 255, 255, 1);  break;
            case "yellow": mat.color = new Color (255, 255, 0, 1);  break;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```